# How to check whether the value exists in array?

Tags: arrays, angular

I want to search particular value in array. For example I have array of users , I want to check particular user is present in that array.

My array is as follows:

```
Array(5)
0:{id: "empty", name: "Choose one..."}
1:{id: "option_1", name: "shilpa"}
2:{id: "option_2", name: "anita"}
3:{id: "option_3", name: "admin"}
4:{id: "option_4", name: "user"}
length:5
__proto__:Array(0)
```

Here I want to check whether the user "admin" exists in the array?

I tried with following but it is returning the result as false:

```
console.log(this.observedByProperties.includes('admin'));
```

Can any one provide solution in this?

Comment: Filter by name then check the length. `.includes` won't search arbitrary properties for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#some` to iterate through array, using `string#includes` check if `admin` is present in the word.

```js
const arr = [{id: "empty", name: "Choose one..."}, {id: "option_1", name: "shilpa"},{id: "option_2", name: "anita"},{id: "option_3", name: "admin"},{id: "option_4", name: "user"}],
  exist = arr.some(({name}) => name.includes('admin'));
console.log(exist);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Array.find to check whether the object with particular value exists,

```
var result = his.observedByProperties.find(t=>t.name ==='admin');
if(result){
 console.log('true');
}
```

Comment: Find will iterate over all items while `some` will stop once the given item is found. Better performance on large set !

Comment: (I'm removing my downvote because OP didn't state if he wanted the item, or only check if it exists)

Comment: @trichetriche i dont think there is a performance issue when using find, the only difference is some will return boolean where find will return the object

Comment: If the item is at the 5th place in a 10 items array, `some` will make 5 iterations whereas `find` will look in the whole array

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `generalized function` which takes `array` and `value` as `parameters` and returns `true` or `false`

```js
const arr = [{id: "option_1", name: "shilpa"},{id: "option_2", name: "anita"},{id: "option_3", name: "admin"},{id: "option_4", name: "user"}]

function containsValue(arr, x) {
    return arr.filter(function(elem) { return elem.name == x }).length > 0;
}
console.log(containsValue(arr, 'admin'))
```

Comment: @user8030367, have you checked this? any help needed?

Answer (score 0):

you could use the filter function for arrays.

```
    let arr = [{id: "empty", name: "Choose one..."}, {id: "option_1", name: "shilpa"},{id: "option_2", name: "anita"},{id: "option_3", name: "admin"},{id: "option_4", name: "user"}];
this.findUser(arr,"Admin");

findUser(array, userName) {
    return array.filter(user => user.name === userName);
}
```